# Location Stops Updating after App Sent to Background

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

OK, here's a tough  one (for me anyway)... My app has a button that checks to see if a user is in close proximity to a business. The button works almost perfectly by doing the following when it is pressed:

- Gets the user's latitude and longitude coordinates
- Passes the user's latitude and longitude coordinates to a PHP script
- The PHP script compares the distance between the user and the business. If the user is within 100 feet, the script returns 1, if the user is not within 100 feet, the script returns 0.
- Lastly, the app then displays an alert saying that the user is less than 100 feet away, or more than 100 feet away

Like I mentioned, this works almost perfectly. I can walk towards a business continuously clicking the button as I approach the building and when I get close enough, the alert will tell me that I am less than 100 feet away.

My problem is that the alert displays wrong information if I send the app to the background while I am walking. For example, I open the app from very far away, then I send the app to the background and approach the business, then when I am right next to the business, I bring the app to the foreground and click the button and it says I am more than 100 feet away. Anyone have any ideas on why this might be happening?

**In my viewDidLoad Method:**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
selector:@selector(appReturnsActive) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification 
object:nil];
```

**In appReturnsActive Method:**

```
- (void)appReturnsActive{

    locationManagerProfile.delegate = self;
    locationManagerProfile.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManagerProfile startUpdatingLocation];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To save battery, location updates are stopped when your app goes to background. You can add a value to info.plist to keep your app updated. But you should carefully consider battery usage.

Comment: Thanks, lets say that I want it to start updating right away when I bring it back to the foreground. I've updated my question to show what the appDidWaken might look like...

Comment: Updating location takes time. If no other app or the system updated location info while your app is in background, you can't get current location immediately.